# Undefined reference to pcl_ros::transformPointCloud

Tags: pcl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am getting  undefined reference to `pcl_ros::transformPointCloud` in the linking phase of `catkin_make`.
This is the source code:

```
void cloud_cb_cam1 (const sensor_msgs::PointCloud2ConstPtr& input)
{
  cam1_data_valid = true;
  
  sensor_msgs::PointCloud2 ros_cam1;
  pcl_ros::transformPointCloud("pf1_link", *input, ros_cam1, *tf_listener);
  pcl_conversions::toPCL(ros_cam1, pcl_cam1);

  if (cam1_data_valid && cam2_data_valid)
  {
    cam1_data_valid = false;
    cam2_data_valid = false;
    pcl_combine();
  }
}
```

My CMakeLists includes these libraries:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(pc_combine)

find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  roscpp
  rospy
  std_msgs
)
find_package(PCL REQUIRED)

catkin_package(
)

include_directories(
  ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
  ${PCL_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)

target_link_libraries( pc_combine
  ${catkin_LIBRARIES}
  ${PCL_LIBRARIES}
)

link_directories(${PCL_LIBRARY_DIRS})
add_definitions(${PCL_DEFINITIONS})
```

Am I missing any libraries?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/223205/undefined-reference-to-pcl_ros::transformpointcloud/) by [Robpuff](https://answers.ros.org/users/25442/robpuff/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2015-12-28

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2016-01-07**:
do you also `find_package` the `PCL` library?

**Comment by [Robpuff](https://answers.ros.org/users/25442/robpuff/) on 2016-01-08**:
Yes, I use `find_package(PCL REQUIRED)`.
I included my entire CMakeLists file
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Your C++ code is using the `pcl_ros` and `pcl_conversions` packages, in addition to PCL. You should also include these packages in your list of dependencies:

```
find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  roscpp
  rospy
  std_msgs
  pcl_ros
  pcl_conversions
)
```

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2016-01-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Robpuff](https://answers.ros.org/users/25442/robpuff/) on 2016-01-09**:
Thank you so much! This worked for me!